# how to make my bmi calculator appear and disappear on click?

Tags: javascript

so i've been browsing trying to get the answer but i dont have found any easy way to do it, if there is any, do you guys know any way that i can do it?

HTML:

```
<main id="main">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="title"> Calculadora - IMC </div>
          <div class="input">
              <label>Nome:</label>
              <input type="text" id='nome'>
          </div>
          <div class="input">
              <label>Altura:</label>
              <input type="number" id='altura'>
          </div>
          <div class="input">
              <label>Peso:</label>
              <input type="number" id='peso'>
          </div>
          <button id='calcular'>Calcular</button>
  
          <div class="result" id='resultado'></div>
        </div>
      </main>
```

JavaScript:

```
function desaparecer(){

    document.getElementById("main").style.display = "none";{
    }
```

CSS:

Comment: have you tried hiding the container instead of main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can toggle a class that hides the container.

```js
document.querySelector('#toggleVis').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.querySelector('.container').classList.toggle('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title"> Calculadora - IMC </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label>Nome:</label>
      <input type="text" id='nome'>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label>Altura:</label>
      <input type="number" id='altura'>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <label>Peso:</label>
      <input type="number" id='peso'>
    </div>
    <button id='calcular'>Calcular</button>

    <div class="result" id='resultado'></div>
  </div>
  <button id="toggleVis">Hide/Show</button>
</main>
```

Comment: thank you it worked! But do you mind giving a simple explaination of the fuction of ```e =>``` and why you used so i can understand what happened?

Comment: @Jorgityo `e` is the event object (which is not used here). The `=>` syntax is an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your HTML Button a trigger on a "OnClick" event

HTML

```
<body>
<main id="main">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="title"> Calculadora - IMC </div>
          <div class="input">
              <label>Nome:</label>
              <input type="text" id='nome'>
          </div>
          <div class="input">
              <label>Altura:</label>
              <input type="number" id='altura'>
          </div>
          <div class="input">
              <label>Peso:</label>
              <input type="number" id='peso'>
          </div>
          <button id='calcular' onclick= "desaparecer()">Calcular</button>
  
          <div class="result" id='resultado'></div>
        </div>
</main>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
function desaparecer(){
    document.getElementById("main").style.display = "none";
}
```

Test Playground : https://jsfiddle.net/yqfspxkd/1/ (CLick Run on the top left first)
Reference : https://linuxhint.com/trigger-click-event-javascript/

Comment: i forgot to add but it has a button above the main that was doing that fuction, but thanks for your response.